# How do I create a new repository in Sublime Merge without Exit Code 1?

Tags: git, merge, error-code, sublimemerge

I am trying to add a new repository in Sublime Merge.

I browse to the folder where I want to go and get this error code.

Is there something I can do to address this?

Thanks!

Error Image-Git Failed with Exit Code 1:

[image]

Comment: Do operations on existing repositories work?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  They do no appear to.  Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Sublime Merge is just a GUI wrapper on the standard `git` binaries; it ships with a version of `git`, but it can also use some other version as well if you happen to have one. There's a setting in the advanced properties that sets whether the git used is the `bundled` version, the `system` version or some other version. If you have `git` installed elsewhere, you could try changing that setting. Otherwise you would need to determine what it is about `git` that's stopping it from working, which isn't entirely Sublime Merge related.